# How can i match same string between two column which one of individual and one of composite

Tags: sql, string, t-sql

For the Northwind. I want to list same last named persons on employees and customers. On Employees table, first name and last name individual but on customers not. How can i match them ? 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf0dE.png)

I want to select same last named persons in a new table

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

This is just odd and you may get zero matches

```
select *  
from employees 
join customers 
on customes.contact = employees.firstName + ' ' + employees.lastName
```

if just last name

```
on customes.contact = like '% ' + employees.lastName
```

Comment: Yes, I want this. Thanks

Comment: If that is the answer you can indicate so with a check